# Cambiar valor de un textView en activity

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenas resulta que tengo el siguiente ejercicio=

Agregue un TextView a la Activity generada con el valor "Español" y un botón con el valor  "Cambiar idioma".

- Al hacer click en el botón el textview debe cambiar su texto a "Inglés". Si
  se presiona nuevamente sobre el botón, el textview debe contener el valor "Español"
  nuevamente

Mi duda era como hacer la parte logica en la activity que yo ya tengo creada, tengo una idea que es la de poner la siguiente linea para que me devuelva el id de mi texto, pero no se como interactuar con el mismo:

```
 TextView tv = this.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez tengas el `Text View` simplemente tienes que asignarle el texto deseado. Para ello puedes utilizar el metodo `setText`. Por ejemplo:

```
tv.setText("Inglés");
```

Para el resto del ejercicio simplemente tienes que ir jugando con estos valores dentro del `OnClickListener` del botón.

Te dejo información sobre [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) y sobre [`Button`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) donde puedes ver todos los métodos que contienen estos componentes.